# Typescript syntax highlighting not working

Tags: android, typescript, codehighlighter

After enabling the Typoscript plugin like suggested by the IDE none of my .ts files show syntax highlighting any more.

I've tried reinstalling android studio after removing all settings folder in appdata, userprofile, program files folder. I've tried with new project and existing ones. I am not able to get the syntax highlighting back.

I'm running:
- windows 10
- Android Studio 3.5

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() {}

}
```

How do I get syntax highlighting working again asif a clean installation.

Comment: Did you try to simply uninstall the plugin ?

Comment: yes offcourse, sorry should have put that in. With the plugin installed, it gave some color but far from what it should be. After uninstalling, no color at all. Just one color text on background. The colors like it is here in the code preview. That is what I had before, now nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventualy reinstalling everything solved my issues.